# Libgdx, TiledMap, and tearing

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures, rendering, tilemap

My TiledMap tears when the window is specific sizes, resized, or the camera moves.

[image: Bleeding]

The tileset is padded by 2px and have tried as high as 10px. Each tile is 70x70.

[image: Testing Tileset]

Here are the pack.json settings,

```
{
    paddingX: 2,
    paddingY: 2,
    bleed: true,
    edgePadding: true,
    duplicatePadding: true,
    maxWidth: 4096,
    maxHeight: 4096,
    filterMin: Nearest,
    filterMag: Nearest,
    ignoreBlankImages: true,
    wrapX: ClampToEdge,
    wrapY: ClampToEdge,
    grid: true,
    fast: false
}
```

Here is the code.

```
Parameters params = new Parameters();
params.textureMinFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
params.textureMagFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
TileMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load(file.getAbsolutePath(),params);
```

So what am I doing wrong? If nothing, does that mean libgdx absolutely cannot handle TileMaps of any sort?

Answer (score 1):

70 is not a power of 2.

Adding,

```
pot: false,
```

to pack.json for TexturePacker resolved this.